# Delete graphic in Excel with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pictures

In some of my worksheets I see pictures and Excel show me the names like "Grafik 4". Now I want to delet them automatically. I have 200 Excel files, always with the same picture and the same picture name.
I tried it like this:

```
Sub Clear_Images()
    Dim directory As String, fileName As String ', sheet As Worksheet, i As  Integer, j As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim myPict As Shape

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    directory = "C:\Users\"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

    Do While fileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

        For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each myPict In wks.Shapes
                If myPict.Name = "Grafik 4" Then
                    myPict.Delete
                End If
            Next myPict
        Next wks
        Set wks = Nothing

        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But in VBA each pictures seems to have the name "Object x" (x are numbers from 1-open).
Has somebody an idea how do I can read out the real name of the picture?

Best,
    Franz

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on Excel 2013 (German language). I inserted some random pictures. They got automatic names like yours i.e. "Grafik 4"

[image]

To delete this shape, I would use this technique:

```
Sub test()

    On Error Resume Next
    Set image = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Grafik 4")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Debug.Print image.Name

    If Not image Is Nothing Then
        image.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Excel recognizes `Shapes("Grafik 4")` despite being it's internal name `Picture 4`
which you can see with `Debug.Print image.Name`